# How to write short circuit conjunction of multiple boolean conditions over same parameters?

Tags: haskell

How can I re-write conjunction of conditions (with early termination) over same parameters?

Let say I have 3 conditions

```
cond1 :: Maybe a -> Maybe a -> Maybe Bool
cond2 :: Maybe a -> Maybe a -> Maybe Bool
cond3 :: Maybe a -> Maybe a -> Maybe Bool
```

and

```
result = cond1 x y .&& cond2 x y .&& cond3 x y
```

where `.&&` is short-circuiting operations for Maybe Bool

```
(.&&):: Maybe Bool -> Maybe Bool -> Maybe Bool
fa .&& fb = do a <- fa; if a then fb else return False
```

I am looking for re-write of `result` such that it takes the list of those conditions `[cond1, cond2, cond3]` and consecutively apply it to tuple `(x,y)` with early termination or any other elegant suggestion.

Thank you

Comment: The haskell boolean operators are short-circuiting anyway; they're lazy!

Comment: That's true, `.&&` there is short-circuiting operation for Maybe Bool. I will update description.

Comment: `a .&& b = (&&) <$> a <*> b`. This short-circuits for both `Nothing` and the acual `Bool`. Do you know about [`Applicative`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.0.0/docs/Control-Applicative.html#t:Applicative)?

Comment: You may wish to have a look at either [Control.Shortcircuit](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/shortcircuit-0.1/docs/Control-Shortcircuit.html) or [Control.Selective](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/selective-0.4.1/docs/Control-Selective.html).

Answer (score 6):

The `Maybe a` types are just a distraction - they might as well be `a`, since all we want to do with them is call cond*n* on them.

So, we have a list:

```
conditions :: [a -> b -> Maybe Bool]
```

and a tuple:

```
inputs :: (a, b)
```

Since the only thing we can do with the conditions in that list is call them with `inputs` as an argument, we might as well do that first:

```
results :: [Maybe Bool]
results = map (($ inputs) . uncurry) conditions
```

and would like to find an f, such that

```
f results :: Maybe Bool
```

meaning

```
f :: [Maybe Bool] -> Maybe Bool
```

There are some interesting functions with that type signature, for example

```
f = fmap and . sequenceA
```

but this may be a little bit less short-circuity than you'd like: if one of the conditions returns `Just False`, we will still evaluate the remainder to see if any of them yield `Nothing`. This may or may not be what you wanted; to do something that short-circuits on `Just False` as well as on `Nothing`, I don't see any approach more clever than writing a recursive function that consumes the list.

Comment: Thank you @amalloy, applying `($ inputs)` was challenging.

Comment: I showed below how you can use this approach but get short-circuiting.

Answer (score 2):

You can get a similar solution to above, but with short-circuiting across the foldable structure, i.e. not having to consume the whole list.

```
(??) :: b -> b -> Bool -> b
a ?? b = \x -> if x then a else b

andM :: (Monad m) => m Bool -> m Bool -> m Bool
andM a b = a >>= \x -> (b ?? pure x) x

shortCircuitOnFalse :: (Foldable t, Monad m) => t (m Bool) -> m Bool
shortCircuitOnFalse = foldr andM (pure True)
```

So if you have a list (which is Foldable) of functions resembling conditions;

```
conditions :: [a -> b -> Maybe Bool]
```

and a tuple of inputs to those functions;

```
inputs :: (a, b)
```

then you can take the same approach as above:

```
results :: [Maybe Bool]
results = map (($ inputs) . uncurry) conditions

whatYouWant :: Maybe Bool
whatYouWant = shortCircuitOnFalse results
```

and a generalised version of `whatYouWant`:

```
gWhatYouWant
  :: (Foldable t, Functor t, Monad m)
  => t (a -> b -> m Bool) -- ^ conditions
  -> (a, b) -- ^ inputs
  -> m Bool
gWhatYouWant cs is = shortCircuitOnFalse $ fmap (($ is) . uncurry) cs
```

Answer (score 0):

`guard` is useful for short-circuiting behavior.

```
module Main where

import Control.Monad
import Debug.Trace

cond1 :: Maybe Bool
cond1 = Just True

cond2 :: Maybe Bool
cond2 = Just False

cond3 :: Maybe Bool
cond3 = Just True

-- | traceShow added to show the short-circuiting behavior
shortCircuit :: Maybe Bool
shortCircuit = foldl1 ((>>) . (guard =<<)) [ traceShow "1" cond1
                                           , traceShow "2" cond2
                                           , traceShow "3" cond3
                                           ]
-- λ> shortCircuit                                                                                                                                               
-- "1"                                                                                                                                                           
-- "2"                                                                                                                                                           
-- Nothing
```